# Why is the image not showing on the browser?

Tags: html, asp.net

```
<header>
    <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark mb-3 fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/_Layout">
                <img src="Logo.png" style="width:40px;">
            </a>
        </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Image not showing on the browser, the image is located in the same folder as the HTML file.

[image]

Comment: does it show when it's not in the anchor tag (<a>) ? just wondering if it could be because of the styles

Comment: or try src="/Logo.png"

Comment: @sonali it does not show when it is outside of the anchor tag or when I tried src="/Logo.png"

Comment: src='~/Pages/Shared/Logo.png

Comment: Although `Logo.png` is in the same folder as the layout it is most definitely not on the same path that the browser is requesting the image from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web application, create a `wwwroot` folder. Inside that create an images folder. Put your image in there.

```
Application
    wwwroot
        images
            Logo.png
```

Your link:

```
<img src="~/images/Logo.png" />
```

---

Note 1: anchor link should probably not be `asp-page="/_Layout"`. Probably `asp-page="/Index"`, or similar.

Note 2: my app is a little different. I'm not positive you need a `wwwroot` folder, but I think the image should be in a different folder than 'Shared'.

Comment: I created an images folder in the wwwroot folder and placed the image there. It worked perfectly! Thank you very much!